# BotFramework ADO.Net Entity Data Model stopped working since project was published to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, ado.net, botframework

I built a bot that I tested in my machine with the Bot Framework Channel Emulator.

But now I get an error accessing the ADO.NET Entity Data Model (which didn’t occur when I ran it in my local environment).

I can access the classes but I can't see to get data from the tables.

Publishing the project into Azure is not enough to ensure that the data is accessible?

Comment: In your Azure setup, do you also have the database setup that is used by your Entity data model?  Check the app.config for your application to see what it's using for the connection.  You must also have a database setup in Azure(a sql server database most likely if that's what your data model is using)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a database in Azure. You cannot use a database in your App_Data folder. This article explains how to convert your database:
[Implementing A SQL Server Database With The Microsoft Bot Framework](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)